# YouCompleteMe not parsing #include

Tags: vim, c++, ubuntu-18.04

[YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe) worked fine until I upgrade Ubuntu from 16 to 18.

Now it doesn't understand `using std::cin;` saying

> no member named 'cin' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'min'?

It also doesn't read in class names defined in my own header files.

I have tried reinstalling YouCompleteMe, `git pull` the latest version, `git submodule update`.

I also verified/updated the path to libclang to `/usr/lib/llvm-8/lib/libclang.so` in .vimrc and the path to C++ standard library to `/usr/include/c++/7/` in .vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py

All the C++ source code compiles without error with nearly identical compilation flags.

Comment: The question is not about how to write c++, but rather about a vim plugin YouCompleteMe which broke after Ubuntu upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the README on [YouCompleteMe github page](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#completion-doesnt-work-with-the-c-standard-library-headers) and run

```
$ echo | clang -v -E -x c++ -
clang version 8.0.0-3~ubuntu18.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)
...
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../../include/c++/7.4.0
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../../include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/7.4.0
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../../include/c++/7.4.0/backward
 /usr/include/clang/8.0.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
...
```

Go into ~/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py
and add the paths after `#include <...> search starts here:` in the flags array with '-isystem' before each and removing the old includes.

```
flags = [
 # ...
 '-isystem',
 '/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../../include/c++/7.4.0',
 '-isystem',
 '/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../../include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/7.4.0',
 '-isystem',
 '/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../../include/c++/7.4.0/backward',
 # ...
]
```

Restart vim and the issue is fixed.